# What is the proper way to patch Wine for a custom PPA?

Tags: ppa, wine, packaging, patch, launchpad

I've been manually applying patches to Wine for use on my own machine, but I want to put it in a PPA for my friends and relations.

Currently I follow this procedure:

1. Get the latest source from an upstream PPA via `apt-get source`
2. Use `patch` to apply my unofficial, unsupported patches.
3. Create a package using `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b`

This is fine for creating a package that will run on my local machine. However I now want to distribute this custom build to others via a PPA.

Is this procedure sufficient, or is there a more correct and/or easier to maintain procedure I should be following specifically for Wine?

Comment: This answer, to another question, might provide a few useful sources - http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/320/how-do-i-create-my-own-php-5-3-3-package-ppa/323#323

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're pretty close with your example steps, but here's what I'd suggest:

1. Grab the sources with `apt-get source wine` and `cd` into the new directory
2. Find what sort of patch system the wine package is based on: `what-patch`; in this case, it tells us we that the wine package uses `quilt` for patch management
3. Since we're using quilt, add your custom patch(es) to the quilt series:

   ```
   QUILT_PATCHES=debian/patches quilt import <your-patchfile.patch>
   ```

   If you have multiple patches, do this for each patch, in the order that you want them applied.
4. Add a suitable entry to the `debian/changelog` file - you'll need to alter the version number to ensure that your PPA version is differentiated from the official version. Typically, you should increment the last version number, and add a tilde (~) followed by your custom version string (eg `~jbowtie1`). The `dch -i` command can help with this too.
5. Build the source package:

   ```
   debuild -S
   ```
6. Upload your source package to the PPA build system:

   ```
   dput ppa:<your-ppa> ../wine*.changes
   ```

   The <your-ppa> parameter is specified on the launchpad page for the PPA you want to upload it to (you'll have to create this beforehand).

It's usually a good idea to do a test build before doing the dput - the `pbuilder` command allows you to recreate what the PPA build system would do with your package (ie, start from a clean install, add required deps, then build).

In this case you would have to set up pbuilder first (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto), then do this before the `dput`:

```
sudo pbuilder build ../*.dsc
```

Comment: This is about perfect. Is step 3 different if I use edit-patch, or am I better off learning quilt details?

Comment: If you use edit-patch, you'll have to apply your existing patch as a separate step. But the outcome will be the same, so it's really your call.

Comment: Use `debuild -S -sa` when initially uploading to your PPA. "-sa" will attach the orig source always.

Answer (score 4):

The [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/6.10/ubuntu/packagingguide/C/index.html) has all the information how to package for Ubuntu including howto deal with patches.

Comment: Can you point me to a more specific section of the guide? I can't quite make the conceptual leap from what's in the guide to understanding how wine patches specifically should be packaged.

Comment: wine patches are like patches in any other packages. You should you a patch system like quilt to add the patches. This allows you to easily remove them from the packages when the patch has been added upstream. Chapter 4 talks about the different patch systems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first build a source package-

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Basic#Building%20the%20Source%20Package

Pushing it to a PPA is very easy for Ubuntu 9.10 or later

Just go to Terminal and type

```
dput ppa:your-lp-id/ppa <source.changes>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy's answer is straight to the point.

Alternatively, you can use `bzr` to handle the source, patches and building/upload.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DistributedDevelopment, starting with https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DistributedDevelopment/Documentation.
While is simplifies some steps, e.g. merging for new upstream versions (if you plan to get ahead of the original Ubuntu package), the original "apt-get source" approach is probably more straight and easier in the end.

Answer (score -2):

[Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) includes a PPA for Wine, once it is selected in Ubuntu Tweak it will stay updated via regular updates

Comment: I know about the Wine PPA, but I want to create my own PPA that includes some custom patches.

Answer (score -3):

From the winehq website:

Open the Software Sources menu by going to System->Administration->Software Sources. Then select the Third Party Software tab and click Add.

Then, copy and paste the line below.

ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa

Then run sudo apt-get update and after it's done sudo apt-get install wine